# Named Pipes from VB6 to WCF

Tags: wcf, vb6, named-pipes

Can I have a VB6 app call a named pipe connection to a service written in C# with a WCF endpoint?

The VB6 project that makes use of named pipes to talk to a service written in C++.  I would like to convert the C++ service to C# (.NET 4.0 preferably).

The VB6 project uses a Win32 call to [CallNamedPipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365144(VS.85).aspx) to send a message to the server.  The payload of the message is a string that consists of the following structure.

```
 [command][data length][data if approprate to the message]
```

I am not able to convert the VB6 side of the application at this time but I am wondering if I can rely on the CallNamedPipe function to send a message to a new WCF service and if they will play well together.  I would see the contract side of the WCF service basically being one method that accepts a string that I will parse.

Also, since CallNamedPipes can receive return data in the outputBuffer parameter, would WCF be able to accomodate this?  Would the contract be something like this...

```
string DoSomething(string command)
```

Thanks for your help!

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is very good, but really shines when using WCF on both sides of the communication channel.  Trying to hook up legacy code to a WCF service is tricky at best.

It will likely be easier to make your C# service use [NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx) directly.  This will give you complete control over how the connection and transfer is handled.  That being said, there is nothing preventing you from doing both (implementing a custom `NamedPipeServerStream` channel, as well as exposing one or more WCF endpoints, from within the same program).  This would provide a way to move forward if you ever want to upgrade the client, as well.

Comment: With a NamedPipeServerStream, can I send back return data or would I be basically doing some type of bidirectional communication on the pipe so that the client would need to "listen" for return data? I would love to upgrade the client but right now it's not in scope and not sure if it ever will be.

Comment: @Brian: You'd basically just do whatever your C++ program is currently doing - it's possible to do bi-directional communication in a single pipe - but I'm not sure what your current program is expecting.

Comment: currently the VB6 code calls with a command like "GiveMeSomeInfo" to the service, which returns the info in the outputBuffer provided by CallNamedPipe. So really it's used like a remote method call. Like you say I could do exactly what the C++ code is doing and PInvoke the Win32 code to setup the named pipe and return the data. I was kinda hoping to make WCF work.

Comment: @Brian: I was more thinking you could use NamedPipeServerStream, on the C# side, to mimick what the C++ code was doing with the Win32 API... It's really a fairly thin API wrapper (that lets you use Stream classes, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately, WCF really kind of dictates the format (on both sides of the channel), so to make it work cleanly with legacy code is not trivial..

Answer (score 0):

Could you call the C++ named Pipes application directly from your C# code using [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CallNamedPipe.html)

Then the wrap the pinvoke service around a WCF Service for easy interop.

Comment: I want to call from VB6 to a new C# application.  The goal is to get rid of the C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a ComVisible class wrapping a WCF client-side proxy, which your VB6 code could call just like any other COM library component.